# How to delete a project from Fabric?

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

I have created a project in Fabric and the app was uploaded to the App Store with Bitcode enabled. I am facing an issue with registering crashes on Fabric. How do I delete my project from Fabric so that I can create it again within Fabric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow below steps to delete app from fabric :

1. Login to https://www.fabric.io
2. Tap on Setting icon which is beside Profile
3. Tap on APPS
4. Choose your app to delete
5. You will see delete app option.
6. You are Done

Comment: Can someone please tell us how to delete the project now after the Fabric has **closed its website**? We migrated to `FirebaseAnalytics` and the integration was a success, but the old Fabric data is just messing up our `500 events limitation` now, since almost all of the events actually got **duplicated**.